# Compile vaadin widgetset from command line

Tags: java, vaadin

In eclipse there is a plugin for vaadin. 
[image]

When mark ***.widgetset** file in your project and click on on **Compile vaading widgetset** it compiles widgetset under WebContent\VAADIN\widgetsets. So my question is how to do it from command line without eclipse? 
Note that: I've searched, but there are example of maven. This is old project and there is not maven configuration in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say which Vaadin version you are using but compiler class at least in Vaadin7 seems to be this:
https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.6.8/com/vaadin/tools/WidgetsetCompiler.html

Not sure of commandline but I have this kind of ANT script for Vaadin7, maybe it will help a bit:

```
<target name="compile-widgetset" depends="init,resolve">
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/WebContent/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/" includes="**/*" defaultexcludes="no"/>
    </delete>
    <java classname="com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler" failonerror="yes" fork="yes" maxmemory="600m">     
        <jvmarg value="-Xms512M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xss8M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true" />
        <arg value="-war"/>
        <arg value="WebContent/VAADIN/widgetsets"/>
        <arg value="${widgetset}"/>
        <arg value="-logLevel"/>
        <arg value="DEBUG"/>
        <arg value="-style"/>
        <arg value="OBF"/>

        <classpath>         
            <pathelement path="${module.src.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="${module.build.dir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" />
            <pathelement path="${module.build.dir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <path refid="widgetset.path"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Compile instructions: https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/clientside/clientside-compiling.html

Comment: vaadin version is 7.6.2.

Comment: See this page:https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/clientside/clientside-compiling.html. Besides the instructions to compile widgetset, there is a link to an example ANT-script at the bottom.

Comment: Somehow your tip helped me. I am almost done. There are ejb issues but I think I will solve it by myself. Thanks a lot

Comment: Here is one more github url that also helped me https://github.com/canthony/simple-vaadin-7-compile-widgetset-ivy

Comment: @gogagubi If you have used a similar or different approach which solved your problem, please consider adding it as your own answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out using this url

```
https://github.com/canthony/simple-vaadin-7-compile-widgetset-ivy
```

I only added **manifest** tag to include dependecies in the **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** file

```
<war destfile="${artifacts}/${warfilename}"
     basedir="${workdir}"
     webxml="${webroot}/WEB-INF/web.xml"
    >
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Dependencies" value="org.jboss.xnio, org.hibernate"/>
  </manifest>

  <lib dir="${webroot}/WEB-INF/lib" erroronmissingdir="no">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </lib>
  <lib dir="${libraries}" erroronmissingdir="no">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </lib>
</war>
```